# How do write template function that can get a substring of a QString or a std::string?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, stdstring, qstring

I'd like to write a template function that can handle both `QString` and `std::string` in order to reduce copied code.  Unfortunately, `QString` does not implement the `substr` member function.  `QString::mid(int, int)` seems to be the Qt analogue.  What is the best way to handle this discrepancy?  Below is the function I have that should act on std::string-like objects:

**Template function:**

```
template <typename StringType>
void do_something(StringType s, StringType::size_type start, StringType::size_type length) {
    // Not defined if StringType == QString
    StringType sub_s = s.substr(start, length);

    // Do something with the substring, for instance:
    std::cout << "Length of substring is " << sub_s.length() << std::endl;
}
```

My guess is that I will need to create another function `get_substr` that is defined for both `std::string` and `QString`, which I can call in `do_something`, but I am not sure if this is the ideal solution.

Comment: Traits/Policy or simple overload seems fine to handle the difference part.

Comment: `QString` has `begin()` and `end()` members, so any [range algorithm](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/string_algo.html) should work equally.

Comment: user zett42 has given an excellent and valid solution, however my answer provides an alternative approach that uses `QString`'s `toStdString()` member function. Thought I'd just provide you with another working solution as it would increase your available toolset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `std::string` and `QString` have `data()` and `size()` members, so you could construct a [`std::basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) for unified string operations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

template <typename StringType>
void do_something( StringType const& s, typename StringType::size_type start, typename StringType::size_type length ) 
{   
    std::basic_string_view sv( s.data(), s.size() );

    auto sub_s = sv.substr( start, length );

    // Do something with the substring, for instance:
    std::cout << "Length of substring is " << sub_s.length() << std::endl;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b026c25d06b78e3)

Comment: `QString::data() /*const*/` returns `/*const*/QChar*`. Which is incompatible with `std::basic_string_view`

Answer (score 1):

As of the time of writing this completed answer, user `zett42` has given a valid solution to your problem. It took me some time to properly install `Qt` and to integrate it into Visual Studio 2017, since now that I have it working I am now finally able to properly build and compile my code to make sure that it works without any issues or bugs.

I think the simplest thing to do would be to use `QString`'s `toStdString()` function. You can write all of your functionality with the default `std::string` version, and then just specialize the `QString` overloaded version that just calls the `std::string` version by converting the contents of the `QString` to a `std::string`. I will use a simple `printString()` function to demonstrate this in the simplest manner; you can take this approach and expand it from here.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>

// defaulted std::string version (full implementation of function)
template <typename StringType>
void printString(const StringType& s) {
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

// specialized overloaded QString version (it calls the std::string version)
template<>
void printString<QString>(const QString& s ) {
    printString(s.toStdString());
}

int main() {
    const std::string str( "I am an original std::string" );
    const QString qStr( "I am a QString converted to a std::string" );

    printString(str);
    printString(qStr);

    return 0;
}
```

*-Output-*

```
I am an original std::string
I am a QString converted to a std::string
```

I think this is the easiest way to achieve what you are asking for. This also has the advantage that if you have to make a modification to your implementation you only have to change the `std::string` version.

Comment: You might use overload instead of specialization.

Comment: You create (unnecessary) copy

Comment: That can easily be fixed with move semantics: I can update the answer to reflect it.

Comment: For your changes, better to use const reference for printString, and remove all std::move. Edited to reflect my last remarks.

Comment: I primary meant the "conversion" from `QString` to `string` does allocation which is not always wanted/accepted. Might be fine in some cases but if strings are huge, it might be really problematic.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah; okay I see what you are saying now. I'm not really that familiar with `QString` or the `QT` library, but was just offering another solution to the OPs question.